# preg_replace error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array of entities that need to be replaced in a large sting but only the first occurrence of each (this is why I am using `preg_replace` rather than `str_replace`), e.g.:

```
$entities = array();
$entities[0] = 'string1';
$entities[1] = 'string2';
$entities[2] = 'string2';
$entities[3] = 'Error String ('; ## this is the one that errors because of the bracket
$entities[4] = 'string4';
$entities[5] = 'string5';

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $new_article = preg_replace('/' . $entity . '/', '##' . $key, $new_article, 1);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning (2): preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset XX
```

What is the best way to get the bracket escaped, and also escape any other character that might be used in regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`preg_quote`](http://docs.php.net/preg_quote)

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape braces. You can do that with `preg_quote()`.

```
$entity = preg_quote($entity, '/');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

```
$entities = array();
$entities[0] = 'string1';
$entities[1] = 'string2';
$entities[2] = 'string2';
$entities[3] = 'Error String ('; ## this is the one that errors because of the bracket
$entities[4] = 'string4';
$entities[5] = 'string5';

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $new_article = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($entity) . '/', '##' . $key, $new_article, 1);
}
```