# php preg_replace with slash character

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$remarks = preg_replace('/'.$searchText.'/i', '<span class="searchText">$0</span>', $remarks);
```

I use the line of code above to highlight the search text that has been entered by the user. It works 99% of the time except when the search string happens to contain a forward slash (/) character. When they do that, php returns a "unknown modifier" error. I've tried escaping the forward slash with a back slash character by adding this line of code ahead of the preg_replace line.

```
$searchText = str_replace('/', '\/', $searchText);
```

That doesn't seem to help. How do I make this work?

Comment: Any reason you're using `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` in your additional line to remove any additional slashes? With the additional line also, have you tried replacing the / with nothing rather than escaping it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg_replace error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712444/preg-replace-error)

Comment: I used str_replace instead of preg_replace because I don't think I need the extra capabilities of preg_replace. If I replace the / with nothing, then it won't highlight the proper text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is for:

```
$searchText = preg_quote($searchText, '/');
preg_replace("/$searchText/i", ...)
```

Comment: After I add that line I get a "Compilation failed: regular expression too large at offset 0" error.